# Change table header with response to button click ,where rows update using JSTL for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jstl

```
<div class="btn-group" >    
    <button type="submit"  onclick="display">DISPLAY SCHEDULE</button>
    <button type="submit" onclick="open" >OPEN SCHEDULE</button>
</div>        
<table  class="table table-striped responsive">
    <!-- column headers -->

    <% Result result = (Result)request.getAttribute("result");%>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th id="change"> Transfer Switch </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <!-- column data  -->
    <tbody>
    <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <c:out value="${row.Schedule_ID}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to change my table header name with button click, so what i did was added a simple java script as follows.

```
<script>
    function display(){
        document.getElementById("change").innerHTML="display"
    }
    function open(){
      document.getElementById("change").innerHTML="open"
    }
</script>
```

but since my JSTL result row gets updated for every loop my header changed too thus ending myself with the same header `Transfer switch`. 
Can i solve this using Jquery on load ??, not sure how to use it.

I heard of solutions to make 2 tables but that's not the solution i am looking for since the table is responsive uses bootstrap and also has some buttons in its rows .

Answer (score 0):

Two things I have changed from your code, now it looks fine,

> 1. Don't use the JS reserved keyword(s) like `open`. Use `openSchedule()` instead.
> 2. For better practice, Use `span` tag for change the text instead of giving id to `th`.

Your HTML with rendered table rows (Assume I could not able to reproduce jsp values here.)

```
<div class="btn-group" >    
    <button type="button" onclick="displaySchedule()">DISPLAY SCHEDULE</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="openSchedule()" >OPEN SCHEDULE</button>
</div>        
<table  class="table table-striped responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><span id="change">Transfer Switch</span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
          <!-- Here I assumed two rows, since It's JSP value I couldn't reproduce -->
          <tr>
            <td>Text1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Text2</td>
          </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Your Script,

```
window.displaySchedule = function(){
   document.getElementById("change").innerHTML="display";
}
window.openSchedule = function(){
   document.getElementById("change").innerHTML="open";
}
```

See [**fiddled demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/vinzykrish/e129er5a/1/) here for live sample.

Comment: your solution does not work ... the problem is not with span or the keyword ( it is just a sample code) problem is the for loop .... the jstl for loops table data , so when the JSTL for loops for the second time the table header changes back to default ( as i inferred from the data...) .. Note: data is thrown from servlet as "result" .